# Rewrite / as _ when saving document in Brive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I downloaded [Brive](https://github.com/x8wk/Brive) which downloads your Google Docs using the Drive API. I'm running into issues with the filename not saving if it has slashes and crashes the application. How can I modify the model.py file to rewrite `/` as `_`?

[model.py](https://github.com/x8wk/Brive/blob/master/model.py)

[brive.py](https://github.com/x8wk/Brive/blob/master/brive.py)

I think I just need to rewrite the "file_name" or "path" on line 74.

[backend.py](https://github.com/x8wk/Brive/blob/master/backend.py):

```
def save(self, user, document):
    self._mkdir(user.login)
    prefix = self._root_dir + user.login + os.sep
    for file_name, content in document.contents.items():
        path = prefix + file_name
        Log.debug(u'Writing {}\'s {} to {}'.format(
            user.login, document.title, path
        ))
        f = open(path, 'w')
        f.write(content)
        f.close()
```

This is the error:

```
[ 2013-01-17 T 06:17:08 Z ] Saving coral.lopez's doc "Lunchbox Monster High 4/7/12" (id: 1GyiuKFZeargO8KfzKS5H9V3PVbgTJufw2PwLaILzRVw)
[ 2013-01-17 T 06:17:08 Z ] Unexpected shutdown, deleting /home/davidneudorfer/google_docs_backup/2013-01-17T061021Z/ folder
### Unexpected error when saving coral.lopez's documents (doc id: 1GyiuKFZeargO8KfzKS5H9V3PVbgTJufw2PwLaILzRVw) ###
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "brive.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "brive.py", line 92, in main
    user.save_documents(backend)
  File "/home/davidneudorfer/Brive/model.py", line 79, in save_documents
    self._save_single_document(backend, document)
  File "/home/davidneudorfer/Brive/model.py", line 105, in _save_single_document
    backend.save(self, document)
  File "/home/davidneudorfer/Brive/backend.py", line 78, in save
    f = open(path, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/davidneudorfer/google_docs_backup/2013-01-17T061021Z/coral.lopez/Lunchbox Monster High 4/7/12_1GyiuKFZeargO8KfzKS5H9V3PVbgTJufw2PwLaILzRVw.odt'
```

Comment: [`the_str.replace('/', '_')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) might be helpful here.

Comment: That did it! Want to post it as an answer and I'll mark it correct?

Line 74 of backend.py: `path = prefix + file_name.replace('/', '_')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`the_str.replace('/', '_')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to turn the path with `'/'`s in it into one with `'_'` in it.